# Automatically convert a MindMap to another app (e.g. MS Project)

Tags: c#, vba, project-management, ms-project, mindmapping

Here is the situation:

- We ran a brainstorming session to find all the tasks we will have to achieve for our project
- Now, I want to create a Gantt Planning (for instance) with all these tasks

We already built a **MindMap** with **Xmind** (I sometimes use Freemind too, or I could also export the Xmind to a Freemind format).
I would like to create a **Gantt Planning in Microsoft Project** (this is what we mainly use here).

My questions are:

- Has anyone of you ever tried to **automate the creation of a Gantt from the MindMap** (using each level of the MindMap as Title and each leaf as Tasks)?
- Would it be possible with **VBA**? Or **C#**? I didn't find much API to Xmind of Freemind, did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can convert your mind map to Freemind, there is some [documentation](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Import_and_export#To_MS_Project) on the Freemind site which provides a couple of approaches to reformatting the Freemind file as an XML file which MS Project can read.

I maintain [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net), a library which can be used to read and write file formats which MS Project works with. I felt sure that someone had already written an add-on for Freemind which allowed you to export mind maps as a project plan using MPXJ... however I can't find a reference to it any more! If you don't mind a bit of coding (in Java, or any of the .Net languages) it wouldn't be too hard to achieve what you want using MPXJ.

Jon

Comment: Thanks for the links. This is not as immediate as I hoped but at least, this would probably work (even if I am not very familiar to Java or .Net).

Answer (score 1):

We're doing exactly that with [STOIC](http://sutoiku.com/post/41279461033/mindmap-perspective).